# I/O limits in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, io, scheduling

I am searching for a method to implement per Jail I/O limits in FreeBSD, as linux have from a long time now.

During my research I stumbled upon:

http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/geom_sched/

My idea is to divide I/O pool in queues, and simply assign one or more queue to a jail according to priority. Queue are server sequentially, and higher priority means you have more queue to do your tasks.

Anyone else have some idea to share, or some data to link?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any mechanism yet that manages specifically per-jail I/O limits in FreeBSD. Also, geom schedulers aren't supposed to be used as a priority mechanism, but rather as I/O scheduling appliances to disk devices (or other geom providers).

The only limits that can be applied to jails are CPU and memory ones, as explained here: https://wiki.freebsd.org/JailResourceLimits